# Find and replace string spanned multiline

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have a file and I need to find a particular string and replace it with another string. The file is created or submitted to us by an external system. The submitted file has 80 characters per line. If a word in the text file doesn't fit into one line, it is split into 2 lines delimited by = symbol at the end of the first line. In the below example, the SAMPLE STRING is split into 2 lines, SAM= in the first line and PLE STRING in the second line. An example is given below

`Line 1 text goes here SAM=
PLE STRING and the other texts of the file.`

Now I need to find if SAMPLE STRING exists, and then replace with some other sample string. I wrote the below code in C#, but unable to find the string if it spans over multiple lines. Please help.

```
string filecontents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("c:\\mytext.txt");
if(filecontents.Contains("SAMPLE STRING")) 
{
     filecontents = filecontents.Replace("SAMPLE STRING", "SOME_OTHER_STRING");
}
```

Comment: Basically you need to concatenate the lines that have an equal at the end with the next line, then do your replacement and finally split the lines that are too long.

Comment: Can the replacement string be a different length? Must the result file have 80 chars per line also? Is the `=` included in the 80 (79 chars + an equals symbol)?

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. Yes, you are correct, the string can be split at any location. So what I am doing is first find the exact string, if found then replace, if not, then loop thru each character in the search string and add a = between them and do a search, till the exact match is found. But it failed because of the new line.

Comment: What algorithm is used when dividing SAMPLE STRING? Three characters? Four?

Comment: I loop through each search key and in each search key iterate each character and add = and line break and rest of the characters and check if it is present. If present, then replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string filecontents = File.ReadAllText("c:\\mytext.txt");

// rebuild the splitted strings
filecontents = filecontents.Replace("=" + System.Environment.NewLine, "");

// remove line breaks from text
filecontents = filecontents.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, " ");

// no need to use the Contains check, use a straightforward replacement (it will do nothing if the string is not present)
filecontents = filecontents.Replace("SAMPLE STRING", "SOME_OTHER_STRING");
```

Once this is done, resplit your text into multiple lines with the same criteria. Since the string that replaces your sample has a different length, if you don't perform the replacement using this approach (or an equivalent one) you will end up with your text splitted into lines of unequal length.

Comment: The `SAMPLE STRING` can be split in **ANY** location, so simple searching for it is in vain.

Comment: That why I'm rebuilding splitted words with my first String.Replace call.

Comment: Thanks for your help and it worked. I searched for SAM=+System.Environment.NewLine+PLE STRING and it worked.